# normalize/standardize data

Tags: r, time-series, mathematical-statistics, ggplot2

I hope someone here can point me on the right direction.
I have the following dataset. I have fish adult and juvenile data that
I want to compare side by side, however, the juvenile fish numbers are
really large and the adult fish numbers are really low. I've heard that I can
normalize/standardize both adult and juveniles so they can be comparable. 
I have heard about the R function 'scale' and I am wondering if it would be correct to use it for this example. Two questions: 1.- what's the correct way to standardize this kind of data to be able to compare apples and apples? 2.-What kind of plots would be useful here to visualize both juvenile and adult data by year, by site or by Run? Thanks beforehand.

```
  runs <- structure(list(Site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Mile3", "Mile55", "Mile61"
  ), class = "factor"), LifeStage = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Adult", 
  "Juvenile"), class = "factor"), Year = c(1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 
  1997L, 1998L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1994L, 1995L, 
  1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1994L, 
  1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L
  ), Run = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Fall", "LateFall", "Spring"), class = 
  "factor"), 
  Total = c(123695L, 208614L, 146115L, 239027L, 35590L, 21813345L, 
   12416014L, 4971935L, 12867720L, 6728047L, 1064L, 764L, 452L, 
   1350L, 83027L, 6181374L, 379220L, 656818L, 45980L, 1264283L, 
   2801L, 1789L, 966L, 374L, 2542L, 561939L, 228029L, 605933L, 
   2901L, 429005L)), .Names = c("Site", "LifeStage", "Year", 
   "Run", "Total"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L
   ))
```

Which translates to this tabular dataset:

```
        Site LifeStage Year      Run    Total
1   Mile3     Adult 1994     Fall   123695
2   Mile3     Adult 1995     Fall   208614
3   Mile3     Adult 1996     Fall   146115
4   Mile3     Adult 1997     Fall   239027
5   Mile3     Adult 1998     Fall    35590
6   Mile3  Juvenile 1994     Fall 21813345
7   Mile3  Juvenile 1995     Fall 12416014
8   Mile3  Juvenile 1996     Fall  4971935
9   Mile3  Juvenile 1997     Fall 12867720
10  Mile3  Juvenile 1998     Fall  6728047
11 Mile55     Adult 1994 LateFall     1064
12 Mile55     Adult 1995 LateFall      764
13 Mile55     Adult 1996 LateFall      452
14 Mile55     Adult 1997 LateFall     1350
15 Mile55     Adult 1998 LateFall    83027
16 Mile55  Juvenile 1994 LateFall  6181374
17 Mile55  Juvenile 1995 LateFall   379220
18 Mile55  Juvenile 1996 LateFall   656818
19 Mile55  Juvenile 1997 LateFall    45980
20 Mile55  Juvenile 1998 LateFall  1264283
21 Mile61     Adult 1994   Spring     2801
22 Mile61     Adult 1995   Spring     1789
23 Mile61     Adult 1996   Spring      966
24 Mile61     Adult 1997   Spring      374
25 Mile61     Adult 1998   Spring     2542
26 Mile61  Juvenile 1994   Spring   561939
27 Mile61  Juvenile 1995   Spring   228029
28 Mile61  Juvenile 1996   Spring   605933
29 Mile61  Juvenile 1997   Spring     2901
30 Mile61  Juvenile 1998   Spring   429005
```

Normalizing/Standardizing is as simple as applying the scale function like this?

```
scale(runs$Total)
```

Comment: Thank you for including data. What kind of comparison between juvenile and adult fish do you want to make. You have already pointed out that juvenile totals are larger.

Comment: I just basically wants to find a method that is statistically correct to visualize both juvenile and adult fish. Someone told me that before I compare the juvenile large values and the adult low values I needed to standardize. I am not a statistician and I would do the comparison of Total fish as is but I guess the data is not comparable because of the large and small values of each life stage. Hope is clear.

Comment: If this was focused on asking for R code, it would be off-topic, but there is a core of how to visualize that saves it.

Answer (score 1):

Standardization doesn't seem needed or especially useful here, as you still have to interpret the results using mean and SD (or whatever else is used to scale).

Good old 16th century (well, 19th century graphically) logarithmic scale seems to work as well as anything:

[image]

Graph drawn in Stata, so please don't ask me for R code.

Answer (score 0):

First, to standardize your data you have to do it in two steps because you have two different populations. So first standardize your adult population and then the juvenile population. With this script, you can do it. It makes first an index of your data rows with the Adult population, and then take the rest.

```
  index <- runs$LifeStage == 'Adult'
  runs$Total_ST <- NA
  runs$Total_ST[index] <- scale(runs$Total[index])
  runs$Total_ST[!index] <- scale(runs$Total[!index])
```

With that, your data is standardized. Data visualization will always depend on the data, so normally I create a lot of plots and see which one is useful. With the above code, you can do some plots. It can be seen that the larger values are always in fall and in Mile3. And that in general adult.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=runs,aes(x=Year,y=Total_ST,col=LifeStage, shape=Run)) + 
  geom_point()

 ggplot(data=runs,aes(x=Year,y=Total_ST,col=LifeStage, shape=Site)) + 
  geom_point()
```